# Necesito un ejemplo matriz con parámetros en php

Tags: php

solo se como declarar una matriz pero no se como indicarle parámetros me podrían ayudar con eso

```
//matris sin parametros 

echo "MATRIS SIN PARAMETROS<br>";
$animal[0][0] = "Perro";
$animal[0][1] = "Gato";
$animal[1][0] = "Lombbriz";
$animal[1][1] = "Burro";
$animal[2][0] = "Murcielago";
$animal[2][1] = "Cocodrilo";

echo $animal[2][1]; echo "<br>";
echo $animal[2][0]; echo "<br><br>";
```

tengo un ejemplo de matriz sin parámetro pero me gustaría saber como indicarle parámetros

Comment: No tengo ni idea de lo que quieres decir con "parametros". Podrias explicarlo un poco mas?

Comment: Quienes tienen parámetros son las funciones o métodos. Las matrices almacenan indices/valores, o lo que es lo mismo, valores en cada índice, pudiendo ser estos valores simples u otras matrices (lo cual las convierte en matrices multidimensionales). Creo que lo que quieres hacer es acceder a determinados valores de una matriz mediante su índice, o sea, mediante la posición en la que ese valor se encuentra. Dicho esto, no se entiende el sentido de la pregunta. Si lo explicas más claro se te podría dar una respuesta óptima sobre cómo hacer lo que quieres. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Saludos te comento lo siguiente en PHP, puedes declarar arreglos unidimensionales y multidimensionales del siguiente modo:

En el siguiente ejemplo declaro un arreglo de una dimensión cuyos valores partiendo desde la posición cero como en cualquier lenguaje es vainilla y luego chocolate; ya después para acceder a ellos mando imprimir el nombre de la variable y la posición que deseo me muestre

```
$sabor[0] = 'vainilla';
$sabor[1] = 'chocolate';

echo $sabor[0].' '.$sabor[1];
```

Si por el contrario deseo declarar un arreglo multidimensional lo puedo hacer del modo siguiente:

Del siguiente ejemplo puedes notar que con la sintaxis de array declaro por dentro de la variable a otros dos arrays, con los valores que deseo pero si son cadenas de texto los pongo entre comillas.

Después si por ejemplo deseo acceder a los valores del primer array dentro de mi arreglo principal como notas lo hago mediante su posición, es decir:

Chocolate se encuentra en la posición cero entonces de las dos parejas de valores que paso entre corchetes la primera sera cero asi:

```
[0][0] //esto me da el valor de chocolate
```

Si ahora deseo acceder al segundo valor de la posición cero lo hago asi

```
[0][1] //esto me dará el valor de barato

$sabores = array(
        array("chocolate", "barato", "econòmico"),
        array("fresa", "caro", "nada econòmico")
    );

    echo PHP_EOL;    
    echo $sabores[0][0].' '.$sabores[0][1].$sabores[0][2];//me va a imprimir chocolate barato ecnonomico
    echo PHP_EOL;
    echo $sabores[1][0].' '.$sabores[1][1].$sabores[1][2];//va a imprimir fresa caro nada economico
```

Saludos espero mi explicación te sirva

Comment: entonces eso serian los parámetros

Comment: tanto para un array unidimensional como para uno multidimensional, te actualice la respuesta para que veas como acceder a los 3 valores contenidos de cada arreglo interno

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: de nada si te sirvio agradecería consideraras marcarla como la respuesta aceptada a tu cuestionamiento